# fill a one dimension space with predefined values

Tags: python, c, algorithm

I would like to fill a length with predefined "subLengths".
let say my subLength are : 3,4,5,6,7,10.
To fill a length of 15 I can use "10+5" , "3+4+3+5" ,"7+4+4" ,"7+5+3" ....
How could I get as an array one of theses results ?
Better : how could I get an array for several good results ? My maximum length is 70  and I guess It could be time consuming to get all the good results for this value.

I am a 3d artist, my coding skill is quiet limited and I just don't know how to deal with this problem .I can use Python or a language looking like C for that.

this code seems to work in my software :

```
def fillBuild(length, subLengths):

    for i in range(len(subLengths)):        
            if subLengths[i] == length:
                    yield subLengths[i:i + 1]
            elif subLengths[i] < length:
                    for subResult in fillBuild(length - subLengths[i] ,subLengths[i:] ):
                            yield subLengths[i:i + 1] + subResult
```

Comment: You want to obtain *all* sums? Are all values positive?

Comment: *"language looking like C"* - is not very helpful. I'd guess it's either MEL (if you are using Maya) or MaxScript (if you are using 3DsMax).

Comment: So you can use elements repeatedly?

Comment: I can use elements repeatedly. 

The C like langage I use is Vex in Houdini.

All the values are positive. I don't need to obtain all sums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursive generator function (Python) producing all possible sublist permutations (with repetitions) of `pool` adding up to `total`:

```
from pprint import pprint

def sub_lists(pool, total):
    for i in range(len(pool)):
        if pool[i] == total:
            yield pool[i:i + 1]
        elif pool[i] < total:
            for sub_list in sub_lists(pool, total - pool[i]):
                yield pool[i:i + 1] + sub_list

pprint(list(sub_lists([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10], 15)))
[[3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
 [3, 3, 3, 6],
 [3, 3, 4, 5],
 [3, 3, 5, 4],
 [3, 3, 6, 3],
 [3, 4, 3, 5],
 [3, 4, 4, 4],
 [3, 4, 5, 3],
 [3, 5, 3, 4],
 [3, 5, 4, 3],
 [3, 5, 7],
 [3, 6, 3, 3],
 [3, 6, 6],
 [3, 7, 5],
 [4, 3, 3, 5],
 [4, 3, 4, 4],
 [4, 3, 5, 3],
 [4, 4, 3, 4],
 [4, 4, 4, 3],
 [4, 4, 7],
 [4, 5, 3, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [4, 6, 5],
 [4, 7, 4],
 [5, 3, 3, 4],
 [5, 3, 4, 3],
 [5, 3, 7],
 [5, 4, 3, 3],
 [5, 4, 6],
 [5, 5, 5],
 [5, 6, 4],
 [5, 7, 3],
 [5, 10],
 [6, 3, 3, 3],
 [6, 3, 6],
 [6, 4, 5],
 [6, 5, 4],
 [6, 6, 3],
 [7, 3, 5],
 [7, 4, 4],
 [7, 5, 3],
 [10, 5]]
```

Comment: thanks for your code , it works fine.
Now, for my use, the number permutations is way to high when I increase the _total_. Anyway, you made me discover the yield function which is nice

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive solution, using Python 2.7:

```
def fill(length, sublengths):
    # IMPORTANT: this function will produce INCORRECT RESULTS if sublengths
    # is not a list of unique integers sorted increasingly.

    fillings = []

    for i, sublength in enumerate(sublengths):

        if sublength > length:
            # if sublength is greater than length, there are no more allowable
            # fillings (because sublengths are unique and are sorted
            # increasingly), so we return the fillings collected so far;
            return fillings

        elif sublength == length:
            # if sublength is exactly equal to length, then only one filling is
            # possible, namely [sublength]; we append this filling to the
            # fillings;
            fillings.append([sublength])

       else:
            # we generate all the fillings that begin with sublength by
            # prepending sublength to all the allowable fillings of
            # (length - sublength), which we obtain by making a recursive call.
            fillings.extend([[sublength] + subresult
                             for subresult in
                             fill(length - sublength, sublengths[i:])])
```

Example:

```
In [2]: fill(15, [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10])
Out[2]: 
[[3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
 [3, 3, 3, 6],
 [3, 3, 4, 5],
 [3, 4, 4, 4],
 [3, 5, 7],
 [3, 6, 6],
 [4, 4, 7],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [5, 5, 5],
 [5, 10]]
```

BTW: `fill(70, [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10]))` produces 1657 possible fillings, so you may want some additional criterion to whittle down the alternatives.

---

Some notes:

- in order to avoid repeating solutions, we will require that each filling be ordered increasingly;
- the key idea is this: suppose that the length to fill is *L*, and *a<sub>1</sub>* <  *a<sub>2</sub>* < ... < *a<sub>n</sub>* are the available sublengths.  To find all the possible fillings of *L* that begin with *a<sub>1</sub>* is tantamount to prepending *a<sub>1</sub>* to all the fillings of *L* - *a<sub>1</sub>*.  This is the rationale for the recursive call in the `else` block of `fill`.  (When a function calls itself, as `fill` does, the function is said to be *recursive*.)
- Since `fill` requires `sublengths` to be free of duplicates and sorted increasingly, we can use the following front-end function to ensure these conditions are satisfied:

  def do_fill(length, sublengths):
      return fill(length, sorted(set(sublengths)))

---

(**NB:** Below is a fairly detailed explanation of what the code does.  If you already understand the code, you can safely skip the rest of this post.)

To better see what's going on, go back to the example above, and start by grouping the solutions according to the first sublength; you'll get the three groups shown below:

```
 # group I
 [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
 [3, 3, 3, 6]
 [3, 3, 4, 5]
 [3, 4, 4, 4]
 [3, 5, 7]
 [3, 6, 6]

 # group II
 [4, 4, 7]
 [4, 5, 6]

 # group III
 [5, 5, 5]
 [5, 10]
```

Now, compare the fillings in group I, all of which begin with 3, with the fillings for 15-3 = 12, using the sublengths [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10]:

```
In [3]: fill(15 - 3, [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10])
Out[3]: 
[[3, 3, 3, 3],
[3, 3, 6],
[3, 4, 5],
[4, 4, 4],
[5, 7],
[6, 6]]
```

If now you prepend 3 to all these fillings, you'll get exactly the fillings in group I.

Now consider the fillings in group II, all of which begin with 4.  Compare them with the fillings for 15 - 4 = 11, using the sublengths [4, 5, 6, 7, 10]:

```
In [4]: fill(15 - 4, [4, 5, 6, 7, 10])
Out[4]: 
[4, 7],
[5, 6]
```

Again, if you prepend 4 to all these fillings you get exactly the fillings in group II.

You may wonder, why did I use [4, 5, 6, 7, 10] as the sublengths in the last call to `fill` above, and not [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10]?  This is because I am interested only in fillings that are increasingly ordered and that begin with 4.  This rules out any fillings that include 3.

Finally, to get the fillings in group III, prepend 5 to all the fillings for 15 - 5 = 10, using sublengths [5, 6, 7, 10]:

```
In [5]: fill(15 - 5, [5, 6, 7, 10])
Out[5]: 
[[5, 5],
[10]]
```

---

If you are so inclined you can repeat the same sort of analysis for each of the subgroups.  For example, you can group the fillings generated by `fill(15 - 3, [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10])` according to *their* first element; you'd get 4 groups:

```
[3, 3, 3, 3]
[3, 3, 6]
[3, 4, 5]

[4, 4, 4]

[5, 7]

[6, 6]
```

These groups are obtained by prepending 3, 4, 5, or 6, respectively, to the fillings produced by

```
fill((15 - 3) - 3, [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10])
fill((15 - 3) - 4, [   4, 5, 6, 7, 10])
fill((15 - 3) - 5, [      5, 6, 7, 10])
fill((15 - 3) - 6, [         6, 7, 10])
```

The analysis above just does "by hand" exactly what the `fill` function does.

One important thing to note is that, with every recursive call, the problem becomes simpler.

For example, in the process of generating filling [3, 5, 7] the following calls to `fill` got executed:

```
fill(15,         [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10]) = fill(15, [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10])
fill(15 - 3,     [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10]) = fill(12, [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10])
fill(15 - 3 - 5, [      5, 6, 7, 10]) = fill( 7, [      5, 6, 7, 10])
```

Note in particular the last one, `fill(7, [5, 6, 7, 10])`.  One can spot its solution by inspection: only one filling of 7 is possible from sublengths [5, 6, 7, 10].  The recursion always ends with the solutions of these trivial cases.  The ultimate solutions get assembled from these trivial ones.

Comment: @ kjo 
thank for you explanation but I can't get it to work.

_ TypeError :  'Nonetype'  object is iterable _